# Oracle SQL - find the character '&' in a string

Tags: oracle

I am intending to do an update (Oracle SQL) for any customer records that includes an ampersand in their name (eg: Joe Bloggs & Co.) to replace this ampersand with the actual word 'and' (eg: Joe Bloggs and Co.).

See script below:

```
UPDATE acuheader
  SET apar_name = REPLACE (apar_name, '&', 'and') 
where client = 'W5' 
  AND apar_id = 'x'
```

HOWEVER, prior to doing this, I would have liked to run a select statement to identify all the customer records that have this issue.

I understand that the ampersand sign `&` is recognised by Oracle SQL as a regular expression `&` so was looking to see if someone could assist with a select statement.

I had initially thought this would work but not 100% certain:

```
SELECT * 
from acuheader 
where regexp_like (apar_name,'[&]') 
  and client = 'W5'
```

Comment: This isn't really answerable because you need to be more specific and provide more information. For example, can you explain what you mean by a 'select script'? Do you mean a 'select statement'? Can you provide your 'script that will replace'? If I do understand the question correctly — and it is highly likely that I do not — you don't need any 'scripts' you just need a single UPDATE statement using the REPLACE function.

Comment: Hi, Jack Douglas - can you confirm if this is more specific ?

Comment: "*I understand that the ampersand sign & is recognised by Oracle SQL as a regular expression*" - that is a wrong assumption. Why don't you simply use `and instr(apar_name, '&') > 0` in the WHERE clause of your UPDATE?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I was hoping to have done the select statement prior to the update so that I knew how many records were being affected.  Are you suggesting that I write the select statement as - SELECT * from acuheader WHERE instr(apar_name, '&') > 0 ???

Comment: Why don't you try your query and see for yourself if it works as you expect?

Comment: @user188667: the UPDATE will return how many rows it updated.

Comment: Sometimes the ampersand really is an ampersand and not the word "and", e.g. Ben & Jerry's.

Comment: The OP just wants a select that gives the rows that would be affected by the update so the OP can verify if it is what is wanted. @user188667 Did you try to append a backslash (\&)?

Comment: Hi Marco, yes you are correct, I wanted to run an update to know how many records contained the '&' prior to running the update - to make sure same no. of records.  Someone had suggested using   WHERE apar_name LIKE '%&%'  which worked perfectly.  Thanks again for everyone's assistance.  Is there somewhere I should make my request as being complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choice for a test would be a simple `LIKE`:

```
SELECT id
FROM acuheader
WHERE apar_name LIKE '%&%'
  AND client = 'W5' 
  AND apar_id = 'x';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to run a costly SELECT statement before the UPDATE.

```sql
UPDATE acuheader
  SET apar_name = REPLACE (apar_name, '&', 'and') 
where client = 'W5' 
  AND apar_id = 'x'
  and instr(apar_name, '&') > 0 --<< only update rows that need it.
```

The UPDATE statement reports the number of rows it changed.

Comment: If this is an ad-hoc statement (which it sounds like it is) I imagine they want to check the results first before applying the update.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to run a select in advance to confirm the no. of records that would be subsequently updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing "a regular expression" with "a substitute variable". How you handle it depends on the interface you're running your query in:

If you're running it in:

- SQL*Plus, you would run `set define off` (or, if you need to accept user input, maybe `set define <some other character>`. You can even set an escape character and use that in your query, e.g. `set escape \` and then `select * from your_table where column like '%\&%';`
- In Toad (and probably other GUIs), you can turn off the substitution variable prompting by right clicking and unselecting the prompt for substitution variable option.